# SCXML parsing IOS

Tags: ios, parsing, scxml

Do anyone have any idea about writing SCXML parsers in IOS ?

I went through this http://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/ and have idea about SCXML.

I need to create parsing architecture now.

Kindly let me know if anyone has idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

SCXML is just XML, so if you simply want to parse the document, you only need an XML parser. This article has a good overview of various XML parsers available for iOS: http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

On the other hand, if you need to execute the SCXML document as a state machine, then you need an SCXML engine. If you create an iOS app using [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)/PhoneGap, then you could potentially use [SCION](https://github.com/jbeard4/SCION) as your SCXML engine, as it is implemented JavaScript. Disclaimer: I am the author fo this library.

Comment: I needed a SCXML engine in IOS :(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about SCXML interpreters that can run on iOS, but uSCXML can generate ANSI-C for the control flow implied in a given SCXML file and you'd only have to provide callbacks for datamodel specific expressions.

```
$ uscxml-transform -tc -i your.machine.scxml -o your.machine.c
```

A scaffolding for the generated machines that passes all IRP tests is given [here](https://github.com/tklab-tud/uscxml/blob/master/test/src/test-gen-c.cpp). In essence, you merely

1. `#include` the [generated C file](https://github.com/tklab-tud/uscxml/blob/master/test/src/test-gen-c.cpp#L20),
2. register the required [callbacks](https://github.com/tklab-tud/uscxml/blob/master/test/src/test-gen-c.cpp#L93) and
3. [run the whole machine](https://github.com/tklab-tud/uscxml/blob/master/test/src/test-gen-c.cpp#L237) until there is nothing left to do.

The example scaffolding is somewhat more elaborate as it will work with all of uSCXML's data-models and supports multiple invoked SCXML interpreters. If you only need one state-chart, the three steps above are sufficient. The generated source code is commented and a stripped down example (from our legacy branch) is available [here](https://github.com/tklab-tud/uscxml/blob/legacy-1.0/test/src/test-c-inline.c) (inline SCXML is not yet supported in new master branch).

We did evaluate the performance of microstep(T) with our approach and it is ridiculously fast, primarily because we precalculate `conflicts(T_1, T_2)`. With the algorithm from Appendix D in the recommendation as a baseline, we achieved a speed-up of 10-20x in the IRP tests (to be published any day now).

If this approach seems suitable but gives you troubles, feel free to [post an issue](https://github.com/tklab-tud/uscxml/issues) on github and I will be happy to add more information.

**Disclaimer:** I am the uSCXML maintainer.