# Fintite State Machine in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, nsxmlparser, state-machine

I want to develop the application as state machine based concept but i dont know about state machine method. I have following  code have as xml format how can parse this or any tutorial is available

```
<scxml initial="idle" name="atm.connRestored" version="0.9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml">
<state id="idle">  
<transition event="atm.connected" target="loading"></transition>
</state>
<state id="loading">
    <transition event="atm.loadSuccess" target="inService"></transition>
    <transition event="atm.connClosed" target="disconnected"></transition>
    <transition event="atm.loadFail" target="outOfService"></transition>
</state>
<state id="inService"> 
   <transition event="atm.shutdown" target="outOfService"</transition>
   <transition event="atm.connLost" target="disconnected"></transition>
</state>
<state id="outOfService">
   <transition event="atm.startup" target="inService"></transition>
   <transition event="atm.connLost" target="disconnected"></transition>
</state>
<state id="disconnected">
   <transition event="atm.connRestored" target="inService"></transition>
</state>
</scxml>
```

Comment: I am also eagerly waiting for answer

Comment: go through this link it may help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489893/scxml-parsing-ios

Comment: go through this link it may help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489893/scxml-parsing-ios

Comment: How was this up-voted 4 times? "Shows research effort..."?

Comment: @NickBull you know the answer?

Comment: @SKM What have you tried so far and what are you having problems with?

Comment: @NickBull I am trying to parse using nsxmlparser delegate methods. I have one button when i click the i want to change the state

Comment: @SKM We aren't here to do your work for you. We are here to help when you get stuck. Perhaps if you post a question showing the code you have written so far and WHY it isn't working as you are expecting, someone might help. But with your question/comment you are currently asking people to do your work for you

Comment: @NickBull hey this is not my question. I am also struggle this place then only i asked

Comment: @SKM Yes, I realise this is not your question. But I see that you have  posted a similar question which someone has answered and your question is equally lacking in showing what you have attempted.

Comment: @NickBull Anyway Thanks for your information..If u know about state machine tutorials in iphone please share